# Prevent Webpack encodeing base64 for image

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, css-loader, webpack-file-loader

I'am learning Vue and building a small app with Vue CLI. During this process, I've met a troubleshoot that made me very confuse, with vue.config.js

This is my vue.config.js's content:

```js
    const webpack = require('webpack')
    const path = require('path')
    const is_production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

    module.exports = {
      publicPath: is_production ? "http://localhost:5000" : "https://my.carpi.test:8080",
      devServer: {
        https: true,
        host: 'my.carpi.test'
      },
      chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module
          .rule('images')
          .use('url-loader')
          .loader('url-loader')
          .tap(options => {
            options.limit = 10000
            options.name = '[name].[ext]'
            return options
          })
      },
      configureWebpack: {
        mode: is_production ? 'production' : 'development',
        entry: './src/main.js',
        output: {
          filename: 'index.js',
          path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
          libraryTarget: 'umd',
          globalObject: 'this'
        },
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /\.js$/,
              exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
              use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader'
              }
            },
            {
              test: /\.css$/,
              use: [
                "style-loader",
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader'
              ]
            },
            {
              test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf|svg)$/,
              use: [
                {
                  loader: 'file-loader',
                  options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: 'fonts',
                    publicPath: 'assets'
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
              use: [
                {
                  loader: 'file-loader',
                  options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: 'images',
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

And below is a sample of my scss file:

```css
    .browser-icon, [class^="browser-icon"] {
      border-radius: 50%;
      height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 500;
      letter-spacing: 0.06em;
      flex-shrink: 0;
    }

    .browser-icon-xs, .browser-icon.xs {
      height: 18px;
      width: 18px;
      background-image: url('../images/Unknown.png');
      background-size: cover;
    }

    .browser-ie-icon {
      background-image: url('../images/IE.png') !important;
    }

    .browser-chrome-icon {
      background-image: url('../images/Chrome.png') !important;
    }
```

What I expected is the background images in scss file should be exported to distribution assets folder with [name].[ext] as defined, but webpack always encode them to base64 format, and the following screenshot is an example:

[Screenshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qreIY.png)

I still need to describe more here is I've also googled many threads about this question, I've also followed those answers but still unlucky.

So please help me out of this headache, any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using `url-loader` which transforms files into base64 URIs.

Ref: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/

Removing this will encode the images using the appropriate url.

Comment: at `chainWebpack` option, I've changed the limit down to `10`, the url-loader stopped encode images, but the exported images could not be read. When I tried to open them by Windows Photo app, it said `It looks like we don't support this file format`. When tried to open them by Chrome, it only showed a small square, not the original. Can I resolve this?

Comment: Again try removing the `url-loader`. There is no need to use it, unless you want base64 encoding, which is not what you want. Setting the `limit` to 10 will just use 10 bytes to encode the image. Why are you using it, in the first place?

Comment: Very strange, when remove `url-loader`, images converted to base64 back again

Comment: There might be valid reasons to bypass the default behaviour in special cases such as open graph meta tags. They do not support base64 images